# Python code for checking train and rain conditions prints 'else' no matter what; how do I fix it?

Tags: python

Code from Uni, was working yesterday now the else: is being printed no matter what answers I input

```
raining = (input("Will it be raining tomorrow? Please enter True or False: "))
trainOnTime = input("Will the train be on time? Please enter Yes, Early or Late: ")
if raining == False and trainOnTime == "Yes":
    print("The train is on time you can walk to the train station.")
elif raining == False and trainOnTime == "Early":
    print("The train is early you will have to drive to the train station.")
elif raining == True and trainOnTime == "Late":
    print("It is raining and the train will be late, you will have to drive to work!", str(raining), str(trainOnTime))
else:
    print("Invalid entry, please try again!")
input('Press ENTER to exit')
```

I expected when I answer "False then "Yes" It will return with "The train is on time you can walk to the train station." or any of the other options when I input the corresponding options.

Comment: Please create a [mre]

Comment: `"False"` (str) and `False` (bool) are not the same. Have you checked the type of your inputs?

Answer (score 3):

When you use `input()`, you input a string "True" or "False" but the code checks for a boolean `True` or `False`, so the condition never matches.
Change to:

```
if raining == "False"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
raining = True if (input("Will it be raining tomorrow? Please enter True or False: ")) == 'True' else False
trainOnTime = input("Will the train be on time? Please enter Yes, Early or Late: ")

if not raining and trainOnTime == "Yes":
    print("The train is on time you can walk to the train station.")
elif not raining and trainOnTime == "Early":
    print("The train is early you will have to drive to the train station.")
elif raining and trainOnTime == "Late":
    print("It is raining and the train will be late, you will have to drive to work!", str(raining), str(trainOnTime))
else:
    print("Invalid entry, please try again!")

input('Press ENTER to exit')
```

You could solve it like this. `raining` will be forced to False if any other input than `'True'`.

Or you could go with this:

```
raining = (input("Will it be raining tomorrow? Please enter True or False: "))
trainOnTime = input("Will the train be on time? Please enter Yes, Early or Late: ")

if raining == "False" and trainOnTime == "Yes":
    print("The train is on time you can walk to the train station.")
elif raining == "False" and trainOnTime == "Early":
    print("The train is early you will have to drive to the train station.")
elif raining == "True" and trainOnTime == "Late":
    print("It is raining and the train will be late, you will have to drive to work!", str(raining), str(trainOnTime))
else:
    print("Invalid entry, please try again!")

input('Press ENTER to exit')
```

Whole code could be even more "pretty".

```
raining = True if (input("Will it be raining tomorrow? Please enter True or False: ")) == 'True' else False
trainOnTime = input("Will the train be on time? Please enter Yes, Early or Late: ")

results: dict = {
  False: {
         'Yes': "The train is on time you can walk to the train station.",
         'Early': "The train is early you will have to drive to the train station."
         },
  True:  {
         'Late': f"It is raining and the train will be late, you will have to drive to work! {raining} {trainOnTime}"
         }
}
try:
    print(results[raining][trainOnTime])
except:
    print("Invalid entry, please try again!")

input('Press ENTER to exit')
```

Some more of functional question. What if the train is "Late" and it is not `raining`?